# Time server not being used

Tags: time, ntp

I have 4 PCs running 10.10 and they all are configured with the same time servers. However, one of them was 6 minutes wrong and it obviously wasn't getting its time synchronized via the defined servers. I tried changing a few of those, but nothing short of a reboot would get its clock set properly. Any ideas what the problem may be?

Comment: What happens if you use ntpdate manually on the problem system?

Answer (score 1):

Is there firewall preventing UDP traffic?

Also, NTP typically corrects time very slowly. You can try stopping your ntpd and run something like

```
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

And see what it outputs. If it's something like

> 17 Feb 20:03:13 ntpdate[3046]: adjust time server 194.100.2.198 offset -311.135718 sec

then it fixed that offset successfully. After starting ntpd again should keep your clock synchronized.

Comment: Nothing blocking UDP & all 4 PCs are on the same local network. The odd part is that the PC had been re-booted just a few hours before the time went so far awry. Another boot set it going straight & it's been in sync since yesterday, but if the problem should recur I'll try the stop & start NTP idea - thanks.